# Is it possible to guarantee that one table can't have any relation with other table (SQL server 2008)?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to create a database where some tables must be completely independent of some others.

I'm grouping them in different schemas (lets say...one is for cars, other for bikes, etc)
so I can have bikes.models and cars.models and I want to make sure these 2 are completely independent.

Is there any way to guarantee this?

Comment: What do you mean by totally independent? Logically (e.g. no one can set up a FK constraint between them) or Physically (separate files)?

Comment: Do you want to ensure that a FK in table1 does not exist as a key in table2?

Comment: I mean logically, is there a way to separate them physically without being in different databases? that is also interesting to me

Comment: @RagnaRock - Physically you could put them on different file groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone with appropriate permissions will always be able to create a FK constraint between the tables.

Don't grant permissions to someone that would do that in error or set up different databases for these different groups of entities instead.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Martin, if you want to create a barrier between these models, keep them in different databases.

You can then give people different permissions on each, and you can't (as far as I know) create foreign keys between databases in any version of MS SQL Server.

Note, however, if people can see both models, they could still run a query to join the data and create spurious outputs.  At some point in time you're forced to trust the sanity of the people who have access to the data.